# How can I manage SQL CE databases in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms

I created a SDF (SQL CE) database with Visual Studio 2008 (Add / New Item / Local Database).

Is it possible to edit this database with SQL Server Management Studio? I tried to attach it but it only offered .mdf and attaching a .sdf file results in "failed to retrieve data for this request".

If so, is it possible to create SDF files with Management Studio as well? Or are we stuck with the simple interface of the Visual Studio 2008 database manager?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create .sdf files with SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

In the File > Connect Object Explorer dialog,
change the Server Type dropdown to SQL Server Compact Edition.

Then in the Database File dropdown choose New Database.... and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 15):

- Management Studio 2005 supports SQL CE 3.0.
- Management Studio 2005 SP2 supports up to SQL CE 3.1.
- Management Studio 2008 supports up to SQL CE 3.5 SP1

I think Management Studio *Express* 2008 does not support SQL CE databases.

Comment: Just to add a brief update now that SQL CE 4.0 is out. SQL management studio 2008 does not support SQL CE 4.0. There are some helpful tools at http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/. Also see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/7588375e-3069-4d68-9365-29feb25b7296 and 1. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

Comment: sqlcetoolbox did it for me. If this was an answer, I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Were you using Management Studio 2005, or 2008?  It should work in 2008 if you create a SQL CE 3.5 database ... just not in 2005.

Comment: When I tried to open up a CE sdf in 2008 studio I get an error "There is no editor available for xxxx.sdf"