# Unable to change server type in SQL Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create and manage SQL Server Compact databases.  The problem is that I can't change the "server type" from database engine. I tried following the directions here: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577222/how-can-i-manage-sql-ce-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio).

[image]

Comment: Does "Options >>" have anything helpful?

Comment: Nope.  I've been all over the web (nothing useful) and all over inside of SQL Server Management Studio and can't find any options.  Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File.. New... "SQL Server Compact Edition query"

[image]

If I go to "Registered Servers", I can connect to SSRS, SSIS in Object Explorer. Right click there, Connect... I get the choice of db engine etc as expected.

If I try to connect on SSMS startup or when I have DB Engine query window open, I can't change it either like above.

Bug? Feature? By design? There probably is some logic to it if I applied some thought...

Edit:

- this is SSMS 2005 I'm using, "full" version
- do you have the SQL CE option in "Registered Servers" (I have SSRS, SSIS, SSAS, SQLCE + DB Engine)
- are you using Express tools?

Edit 2:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955965

You need "SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 Query Tools (SSCESqlWbTools-language.msi)"

Comment: Only options in file -> new are "Query with Current Connection", "Database Engine Query" and "Policy".  Query with current connection just brings up the screen I took a screenshot of.

Comment: When I look in registered servers I only have Database Engine as an option.  When I choose to register a new server, the drop down is disabled there as well.  When I go to the about screen it says Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.  No where in there does it say anything about express, even where the version numbers are.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as answered.  I followed your link and ran into a few more issues but ultimately solved it.  I ended up having to install SSCESqlWbTools.msi off of the SQL Server Installation media.  I'm not sure if it's available for download anywhere else.  Thanks for your time and assistance gbn :)