# Creating SQL statements for creating tables in SQLce database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-ce

I'm starting to learn database, and I will work with SQLce. Is there some type of library that can assist in creating the proper SQL statements for creating tables etc? (Not for query of the database, as I plan to use LINQ).  I'm not thinking an MS library, but some amateur project maybe..

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to download [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b).  The SSMS tools let you connect to SQL CE as well as the full blown SQL Server databases, and best of all it's free.  You can create your tables via the GUI, and then instead of saving the table, you could have it show you the SQL script instead and learn that way.  Everything you do in the GUI executes T-SQL behind the scenes and you have the option of saving all that SQL and running it yourself.

See this stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577222/how-can-i-manage-sql-ce-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio) too for some more details.

Comment: SSMS does not allow scripting, only GUI table design. For scripting, I have a open source library here: http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com