# Copy a SQL Server Database to .SDF file using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sdf

I have a SQL Server running on my local network, and want to be able to check out a local copy of it as an SDF file to work with on the move. Is this possible to do in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I have fiddled with the following and think it should meet your needs.

http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

I became aware of it while conversing this similar question:

[SQL to SQL CE: How to read an SQL or Access database and write it out as SQL CE database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6407107/261997)

***Note*** with the codeplex project you have access to the add-in which will give you the end result you are looking for, or the *source code* - if you only want to see the code.