# Data for MVC 3 code first app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

There is no way on earth this is supposed to be this hard. For 30 hours straight I have been trying to populate a code first database with data. I have tried using a sql server compact instance and a sql server express instance.

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 sp1 and my sql server is SQL Server 2008 R2 (express). Firstly, any database created by the EF I cannot open with management studio. Any database created with the correct schema by management studio cannot be hooked up to the visual studio app. I was under the impression if I pointed to that file EF would hook up to it. The schema is correct because I exported it from an EF created DB. However, that does not work and I get an error that the database already exists.

After painstaiking adding data to a EF created db through the visual studio database tools with scripts, the site would not run, I got an error that the database log file was different or the file was corrupted.

If someone could please just tell me how this is SUPPOSED to work, I would appreciate it. The project is ready to go, I just need to load it with production data and get it uploaded, of course it was due yesterday.

Here are some more details if you need them:
I use this following line of code in the global asax code file when trying to create db's, and I comment it out when trying to connect to a db:
Database.SetInitializer(new storagePropertyInitializer());

A few of the connection strings I have tried:

```
<add name="storageContext" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;Database=irrStorage;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|irrStorageV12.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="storageContext" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=storagePropsDB;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|irrStorageProperties.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="storageContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|irrStorageProperties.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Thanks,
John

Comment: any reason you have to address the DB file directly instead of by the SQL server instance name + default catalog?

Comment: @BrokenGlass : auto attach databases work like this when included in app_data

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to open the db in sql management studio if you have an sdf file.

[How can I manage SQL CE databases in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577222/how-can-i-manage-sql-ce-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio)

I realize it doesn't address the other issue but your data import may work this way. Note your website must not be running or the db will be in use. Detach when done working with it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have sql server compact ce 4 running and that won't work with sql server management studio.

Comment: ah ya. sorry : ) in that case try http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/ or   the vs2010 sql tools if you arent already running them:  http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html